# How do I append a Carriage Return character to a string?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am writing to a USB and need to append with the carriage return character.

Right now I'm doing:

```
usbSerial.write("CMD01".toByteArray())
```

But it needs CR added to the end.  How do I add that to the current string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try use the `\r`:

```
usbSerial.write("CMD01\\r".toByteArray())
```

Comment: Thank you!  I forgot to escape the backslash.

Comment: Why does the backslash need to be escaped? A single backslash creates a \r.